# fileExistsAtPath gets filename with just a path?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dropbox-api

I'm working with `Dropbox API` and I'm loading images into the app's `Documents directory` using the API delegate method `loadFile:intoPath:`.  Dropbox's completion callback method, `restClient:loadedFile:`,  fires ok with `(NSString*) destPath` as the second param.  Each destPath that is returned for each file is the same, something like:

```
/Users/<myID>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<Device #>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<App #>/Documents
```

But when I call this:

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, 500, 500)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
imageView.image =  [UIImage destPath];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

... I get four distinct images!  How is this happening?  How is Dropbox able to get the distinct images with the same exact path?

Comment: Related, I think the data being fetched could go in `Library/Caches` because it can be recreated. Its in between user created content in `Documents` and transient data in `tmp`. Also, if the user wants the docs in Dropbox but *not* iTunes or iCloud, then you should also set `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`. See [iOS File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Comment: `loadedFile` doesn't have an argument called `destPath`. Did you mean `localPath`? And did you mean the *first* param instead of the second?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I get four distinct images?" Your code has a single `UIImageView`... are you saying that single `UIImageView` displays all four images at once? (Maybe a screenshot would help?)

Comment: Finally, the title of the question mentions `fileExistsAtPath`, but I don't see anything like that in the body of the question. Perhaps you could share the part of the code that uses that method?